# Ignore rest of input

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

What's the preferred way to ignore rest of input? I found one somewhat verbose way:

```
ignore_rest --> [].
ignore_rest --> [_|_].
```

And it works:

```
?- phrase(ignore_rest, "foo schmoo").
true ;
```

But when I try to collapse these two rules into:

```
ignore_rest2 --> _.
```

Then it doesn't:

```
?- phrase(ignore_rest2, "foo schmoo").
ERROR: phrase/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: @lurker: I see, thank you for explanation. Could you add this comment as an answer? It does answer the "what's the preferred way" question here.

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't read what you had correctly. In actuality, `ignore_rest --> [_|_].` will give an instantiation error. The two answers already posted are the best alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to state that there is a sequence of arbitrarily many characters. The easiest way to describe this is:

```
... -->
   [].
... -->
   [_],
   ... .
```

Using `[_|_]` as a non-terminal as you did, is an SWI-Prolog specific extension which is highly problematic. In fact, in the past, there were several **different** extensions to/interpretations of `[_|_]`. Most notably Quintus Prolog did permit to define a user-defined `'.'/4` to be called when `[_|_]` was used as a non-terminal. Note that `[_|[]]` was still considered a terminal! Actually, this was rather an implementation error. But nevertheless, it was exploited. See for such an example:

> David B. Searls, Investigating the Linguistics of DNA with Definite Clause Grammars.  NACLP 1989.

Comment: How about "expansions of `[_|_]`" instead of "extensions to `[_|_]`"? (To me, both make some sense...)

Comment: It is an extension w.r.t [(W)DTR 13211-3](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#dcg). Some implementations may produce some expansion but that is not a defining notion.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use `phrase/3` instead of `phrase/2`? For example, assuming that you have a `prefix//0` non-terminal that consumes only part of the input:

```
?- phrase(prefix, Input, _).
```

The third argument of `phrase/3` returns the non-consumed terminals, which you can simply ignore.

Comment: This succeeds also for `phrase(prefix,[p,r,e,f,i,x,t,e,x,t|non_list])`

Comment: Indeed, that sounds like a good idea. I asked the question because I wanted to just check how far my unfinished set of rules can go on a certain file, and this looks like a much better fit. XY problem, I guess…